# NodeJS ReferenceError Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I just started to learn NodeJS and ran into a problem while learning modules.

I have 2 files place in the same directory, the first is `app.js` and the second is `hello.js`. 
In the `app.js` I wrote :

```
const hello = require('./hello');
console.log(me);
```

In the second file, the `hello.js` file, I created an object and then exported it using `module.exports` :

```
let me = {
    name : 'Bao Chan',
    age : 20,
    job : 'Developer',
    hobbies : ['Listen music', 'Play Videogames']
}

module.exports = me;
```

Then I saved 2 files and typed `node app.js` in the cmd but an error appeared :

```
ReferenceError: me is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Web Dev Assets\Projects\nodejs-tut\app.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I've been stucking here for like an hour and still haven't figured it out, I don't know if I've missed installing anything or anything's wrong with my code, please help me, thank you guys so much.

---

**Thank you guys so much, I've found the solution.**

Comment: use `const me` instead ,`let me` only within module scope,

Comment: You're requiring the hello file in a variable called `hello` not `me` (even though me is what you actually called it in the `hello.js` file. Try `console.log(hello)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

**hello.js**

```
let me = {
    name : 'Bao Chan',
    age : 20,
    job : 'Developer',
    hobbies : ['Listen music', 'Play Videogames']
}

module.exports = {
    me: me
};
```

**app.js**

```
const hello = require('./hello');
console.log(hello.me);
```

Comment: No problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **me** with the const which you have used for importing your file which is **hello** here

```
Try console.log(hello,"---")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're requiring the hello file in a variable called `hello` not `me` (even though `me` is what you actually called the object in the `hello.js` file. Try `console.log(hello)`

Answer (score 0):

just change the variable name `hello` to `me`

```
const me = require('./hello');
console.log(me);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Call it `hello.me`

```
const hello = require('./hello');
console.log(hello .me);
```